# CSS animation of scale & color together causes font pixelation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I fire `css` animation of `font-icon` by adding it a class. The animation scaling icon from 1 to 30, and change `color` from `#000` to `#ff0000`.

While it works fine in mozilla, it will make icon scales like if it was low quality png image in chrome, opera and safari. Can't check ie.

It can be fixed in chrome and opera by isolating color animation in `::before` pseudoelement.

But in safari even just scale animation alone treats `font-icon` like png image.

As animation is finished, icon recover its font nature, and pixelation disappears.

Examples:

1. works only in mozilla http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/Kgrpjq
2. works in mozilla, chrome, opera http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/BLzoWp

Code, that works properly only in mozilla:

```
<div>
  <h1></h1> 
</div>
```

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;

  font-size: 34px;

  cursor: pointer;
}

h1::before {
  content: 'A';
}

h1.anima {
  animation: anima;
  -webkit-animation: anima;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anima {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1);
      color: #000;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(30);
      color: #ff0000;
    }
}

@keyframes anima {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1);
      color: #000;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(30);
      color: #ff0000;
    }
}
```

```
$('h1').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('anima');
  var _this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    _this.removeClass('anima');
  }, 5000);
});
```

CSS changes, that helps chrome and opera:

```
h1.anima::before {
  animation: anima-before;
  -webkit-animation: anima-before;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anima {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(30);
    }
}

@keyframes anima {
  0% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(30);
    }
}

@keyframes anima-before {
  0% {
      color: #000;
    }
    100% {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anima-before {
  0% {
      color: #000;
    }
    100% {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know better way to make chrome and opera animates properly without pseudoelement hack? And who knows what's wrong with safari, and how pixelated scaling can be fixing in it?

**UPDATE:**
As @ZBerg has mentioned in his comment: "font smoothing options have a wide array support varients. If something has affected your desktop profile it may have a knock on effect (google - smooth edges of screen fonts)".
Taking into account, that I haven't no more problems with chrome (but really had it as you can see via screenshot, linked in comment), something has really affected my desktop (but I can't google smth exactly about smoothing issue while scaling).
On the whole, I guess that the full answer to my question must include:

- the decision for safari (or explanation what's wrong with it);
- (optionally) explanation of what was wrong with chrome.

Under explanation I mean link to the issue report or regarding chrome the way to reproduce the error.

Comment: Just tested both in chrome and ffox. Both looked good for me. Win 7. (chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m) (ffox 48.0.2)

Comment: @ZBerg Now it really works! I'm not insane. I've made a screenshot of this bug in chrome (it's a pity it's not a giff). http://savepic.ru/11445211.png

Comment: And it still doesn't works in safari(9.1.3 (10601.7.8)). Gif screenshot http://savepic.ru/11464666.gif

Comment: @ZBerg I have no idea, what was wrong with my chrome (same ver. as yours) on friday %). But thanks for testing!

Comment: I did some research into this -> apparently, font smoothing options have a wide array support varients. If something has affected your desktop profile it may have a knock on effect (google - smooth edges of screen fonts)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works for me is scale the parent, 'div' in this case and made the scale over him.
CSS

```
div.anima {
 animation: anima;
 -webkit-animation: anima;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

JS:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
```

as follows:
[updated](http://codepen.io/tarod_spj/pen/XjNgqE)

Comment: It's a pity, your variant doesn't work in safari. And since last update in question it doesn't matter for chrome.

Comment: ups true sorry!